# How to execute onload function javascript from a python file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests

I want to get data from html page, but the page has onload functions which aren't executed when I use the get method of requests.Session().

```html
with Session() as s:
  s.get('https://o2.amdm.pro/amdm/S/S/S/insure/Portfolio#/entityHandle=01%7CPD%7C00000000000001384776%7C0001%7C0001', stream=True)
```

My question is, how to execute those functions as if I was in a browser to get the missing data in order to fill the main div ? Or at least, load the page in a browser and get the html from this page fully loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My question is, how to execute those functions as if I was in a browser to get the missing data in order to fill the main div ?*

You need tool with JavaScript support for that, if you want one similar in usage to `python-requests` I suggest giving a try [Requests-HTML](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/).

*load the page in a browser and get the html from this page fully loaded*

For that you need web automation tool, here I suggest trying *Selenium*.

Comment: requests-html seems to do the job, but there's something I don't understand, I want to keep cookie sessions but it says that : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nicol\Desktop\Nouveau dossier\test.py", line 71, in <module>
    resp.html.render(timeout=20, send_cookies_session=True)
TypeError: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'send_cookies_session'